# Any suggestion on rss reader in emacs

Tags: emacs, rss, elfeed

Is there a decent rss reader in Emacs? I was happy with rss when there's google reader, after its shutting down for so long time, I'm still missing it and haven't find any comparable alternative.

Also how do people watch the updates in stackoverflow? rss, or any specific apps? I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 4):

[Newsticker](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/newsticker.html#Reading-News) seems like a good option. It's already inside Emacs; just call it with `M-x newsticker-show-news`. Add RSS feeds with `a` and visit articles with `v`. Go to next feed with `f` and previous with `F` or to next item with `n` and previous with `p`. You can nmark items as inmortal with `i` to stay as unread. It's customizable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Elfeed](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed) or [Gnus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusRss). I'm on Mac too, I use Elfreed and [ReadKit](http://readkitapp.com/) myself, both of them support export/import OPML.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any good example of elfeed or Gnus to start with? Seems readkit can not pull rss data when it's too old?